# removing compulsary .json extension for API Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

is there a a way how to remove the compulsory `.json` extension from url? For example, I have a route `/api/1.0/users.json` and I would like to have just `/api/1.0/users`, which just shows warning that I don't have the index template set up.

Ideally, I would love to keep the option to have both XML and JSON output, bit have the json as a default that would not require the `.json` extension.

I use the crud plugin and my route looks like:

```
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
    $routes->resources('Users');
});
```

Using CakePhp 3. I am new to cake and so all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You could use the request handler component and do something like this in the app controller beforeFilter

    `if(!$this->request->is('xml')) {
       $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not compulsory, it is just a tool for debugging and fast development. The right way of getting a json response, is telling Cake you want a json response using the HTTP headers.

Just send the `Accept: application/json` header in your request. When using jquery, do this:

```
$.ajax({url: '...', dataType: 'json', ...})
```

You can also force to ignore the headers in the controller:

```
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, requesting the right response type is the solution. Somehow, setting renderAs did not work, not any of  similar attempts.